# Liquibase gradle fails with validation issue

Tags: mongodb, gradle, liquibase

I tried deleting the `databasechangeloglock` but that didn't help.

This is the mongo and liquibase config

```
liquibase {
  activities {
     main {
        changeLogFile 'liquibase/changelogs/changelog-master.json'
        url 'mongodb://r**t:pas***d@localhost:27017/db?authSource=admin'
        driver 'liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoClientDriver'

    }
}
```

```
[2021-11-22 23:25:29] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] Unexpected error running Liquibase: Could not execute
liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Could not execute
        at liquibase.nosql.lockservice.AbstractNoSqlLockService.acquireLock(AbstractNoSqlLockService.java:182)
        at liquibase.nosql.lockservice.AbstractNoSqlLockService.waitForLock(AbstractNoSqlLockService.java:118)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$1(Liquibase.java:218)
        at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:160)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:159)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:138)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:2277)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:215)
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:201)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1761)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.lambda$run$0(Main.java:361)
        at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:160)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:159)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:138)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:222)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:226)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:360)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:193)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:145)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:193)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:156)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Could not execute
        at liquibase.nosql.executor.NoSqlExecutor.execute(NoSqlExecutor.java:182)
        at liquibase.nosql.executor.NoSqlExecutor.execute(NoSqlExecutor.java:173)
        at liquibase.ext.mongodb.lockservice.MongoLockService.adjustRepository(MongoLockService.java:101)
        at liquibase.nosql.lockservice.AbstractNoSqlLockService.init(AbstractNoSqlLockService.java:101)
        at liquibase.nosql.lockservice.AbstractNoSqlLockService.acquireLock(AbstractNoSqlLockService.java:154)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error -1: 'unknown option to collMod: validationAction' on server localhost:27017. The full respo
nse is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "unknown option to collMod: validationAction"}
```

What could be the problem here? Is there a way I can validate the json file that has mongo dml script.

Answer (score 0):

Your liquibase is locked, you must unlocked it on databasechangeloglock by setting the **locked** value to false

[image]